# Split string to get all but the last element

Tags: split, ansible, formatting

Here is my playbook

```yaml
---
- name: This is a hello-world example
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    mystr: "I.To.Be.war"
  tasks:

    - name: Hi
      debug:
        msg: "{{ mystr.split('.') | first | trim }}"
```

Output:

```
I
```

The `trim` filter is to get rid of `\r\n` at the end of the variable incase it has.

However, I wish a generic solution that should print everything before the last element of the split delimiter, i.e.: `.`.

Expected output:

```
I.To.Be
```

Note: I do not want a solutions like `"{{ mystr.split('.')[0][1][2] }}"` as it is not generic in nature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Apply the `trim` filter to every element of your list using the `map` filter
2. Using python list slicing to get everything but the last
3. Join the elements back

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug \
-a "msg={{ (mystr.split('.') | map('trim'))[:-1] | join('.') }}" \
-e "mystr=I.to.be.war"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "I.to.be"
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a regex to match the first part of the string

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug \
-a 'msg={{ mystr | regex_replace("^(.*)\\.[^.]*$", "\\1") }}' \
-e "mystr=I.to.be.war"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "I.to.be"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing how you tested it.

Answer (score 4):

Since your requirement seems to be about getting the name of a file without its extension, mind that there is a extra Jinja filter, [`splitext`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names), purposed for that:

Where, the task

```yaml
- debug:
    var: "'I.To.Be.war' | splitext | first | trim"
```

will give your expected

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  '''I.To.Be.war'' | splitext | first | trim': I.To.Be
```

---

*While the filter splitext is actually returning a tuple, more convenient than a regular `split`:*

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  '''I.To.Be.war'' | splitext | trim': ('I.To.Be', '.war')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Ansible's [`regex_replace()`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) filter:

```
mystr | regex_replace('\\.[^.]+$', '')
```

Comment: how about is the delimiter is `/` ?

Comment: `regex_replace('/[^/]+$', '')`

Comment: @Ashar: please read [How much effort is expected from SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9401096). Asking this kind of clarification in comments with your experience/reputation and knowing the number of questions you already asked on the ansible tag is very close to showing total disrespect to people you ask help from.

Comment: @Zeitounator sorry for that, however, i happened to overlook another post's solution and was trying `/` instead of `.` which obviously did not work is why I posted the comment. i was able to tweak the solution proposed here for the different delimiter. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To create a directory as an Ansible task without a subfolder defined in a path in a variable:

```
- name: "Create folder"
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: '{{ sample_variable_name_from_group_vars_all | regex_replace("^(.*)\\.[^.]*$", "\\1") }}'
    state: directory
```

Be aware that this example has a folder `group_vars` with a file called `all`
and a variable inside for example:

```
---
sample_variable_name_from_group_vars_all: /var/www/mywebsite/subfolder
```

The task will create the directory: `/var/www/mywebsite`